# Storing NSObject using NSKeyedArchiver/ NSKeyedUnarchiver

Tags: objective-c, class, nsobject, nskeyedarchiver

I have a class object like;

BookEntity.h

```
    import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

    @interface BookEntity : NSObject<NSCoding> {

        NSString *name;
        NSString *surname;
        NSString *email;
    }
@property(copy) NSString *name,*surname,*email;
@end
```

BookEntity.m

```
#import "BookEntity.h"


@implementation BookEntity
@synthesize name,surname,email;
- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{

    [coder encodeObject: self forKey:@"appEntity"];

}   
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {

        self = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"appEntity"];

    }
    return self;
}
```

and I assign some values to this class,

```
BookEntity *entity = [[BookEntity alloc] init];
entity.name = @"Stewie";
entity.surname = @"Griffin";
entity.email = @"sg@example.com";
```

so I want to store this class using NSKeyedArchiver and restore with NSKeyedUnarchiver.

I write to file but when I retrieve this file the entity has any value.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the `NSCoding` protocol is incorrect. You shouldn't be archiving the object itself, you should be archiving the **properties** of your object and then unarchiving them afterwards. This is how you would do it:

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.surname forKey:@"surname"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.email forKey:@"email"];
}   
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        self.surname = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"surname"];
        self.email = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"email"];
    }
    return self;
}
```